# Angular Form with Angular-material

Tags: angular, forms

[image]

guys i have this problem if i use material input forms, this is the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <form class="example-form">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Ex. Pizza" value="Sushi">
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>Leave a comment</mat-label>
        <textarea matInput placeholder="Ex. It makes me feel..."></textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home.component';
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {MatFormFieldModule} from "@angular/material/form-field";
import {MatInputModule} from "@angular/material/input";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

I installed material and expected the form to work well instead it works poorly

Comment: It seems you need to bind your <input> and <textarea> to a ngModel, since you use Template Driven Forms: https://angular.dev/guide/forms/template-driven-forms#bind-input-controls-to-data-properties

It is just a guess because to me, it is hard to interpret the expression "it works poorly".

Comment: According to the screenshot at the start of your post: You might lack a style-import: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#using-a-pre-built-theme

Comment: Please describe what exactly works poorly. Maybe also add some reproduction steps or a full stackblitz reproduction.

Comment: Thanks guys, was a problem of Bootstrap and Angular Material conflict dependency